# Create catalog from external delta tables (stored in S3)

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, delta-lake

I have a bunch of delta tables stored in S3. I created them using the next code:

```
DF.write.format("delta").option("path","s3a://deltalake_silver/general_schema/table_a").saveAsTable("general_schema.table_a")
```

The table is created in the 'general_schema' schema, if I execute this code immediately after the table creation:

```
spark._jsparkSession.catalog().tableExists("general_schema", "table_a")
```

I get **True**

But if I create a new spark session or restart the notebook cluster, the result is **False**. Actually, if I run:

```
spark.sql("show tables from general_schema").show()
```

It says:

> AnalysisException: [SCHEMA_NOT_FOUND] The schema `general_schema` cannot be
> found. Verify the spelling and correctness of the schema and catalog.
> If you did not qualify the name with a catalog, verify the
> current_schema() output, or qualify the name with the correct catalog.

This is the way I'm creating the spark session, should I add something in here to start my catalog from the S3 bucket?

```
builder = SparkSession.builder.appName("MyDeltaLakeApp") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", aws_access_key_id) \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", aws_secret_access_key) \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.4") \
    .config('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access', True) \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem") \
    .config("spark.delta.logStore.class", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.S3SingleDriverLogStore") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")


spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48416385/how-to-read-spark-table-back-again-in-a-new-spark-session) looks like a similar issue